CMake library dependency on compiled IDL file
I want a repo of C++ source code that is built into several static libraries. The idea is that this repo is then included in another project as a submodule, and those libraries are included in the final executable as a dependency.
To build the repo into libraries, I first need to compile some google protocol buffer IDL files into C++ source code, which is subsequently compiled into the libraries.
So my library build process needs to follow this order:

Use (pre-installed) protocol buffers compiler to compile IDL files into C++ .h/.cpp files
Compile static library files

It must follow this order otherwise the static library compilation will fail, because the source code from IDL compilation will not have been generated.
I have seen posts like this How to control subdirectory compiling order of cmake? and Specify order for building subdirectories CMake but they seem to address linking ordering, but my problem is order of compilation.
Can someone provide a simple example of how my CMakeLists.txt file should look to achieve the above?

What exactly is your question? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

This question is similar to: How do I condition the build of one target on the execution of another target's binary product?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

add_dependency is what you want.  A quick scan of the duplicate I linked looks like it has an example you can probably adapt.

if the output of the generation step lists the source files cmake should automatically add the dependency

Don't you get this behavior for free with the Protobuf CMake package, more specifically the protobuf_generate_cpp command?
